# ReactiveUI ReactiveCommand canExecute using Subject<bool> not working

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I am using reactive ui in WPF application.
There is base class for validation:

```
public abstract class ReactiveValidatingScreen : ReactiveScreen
{
    public Subject<bool> ValidationObservable { get; } = new Subject<bool>();

    private void Validate(string propertyName)
    {
        // ... some logic
        var isValid = GetValidationResult();
        ValidationObservable.OnNext(isValid);
    }
}
```

And view model:

```
public sealed class UserLoginViewModel : ReactiveValidatingScreen
{
    public UserLoginViewModel()
    {
        Login = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(ValidationObservable, x => LoginImpl());
    }
}
```

My login button always disabled, while there is a call:

```
ValidationObservable.OnNext(true);
```

when validation passed.

But if I change to:

```
public sealed class UserLoginViewModel : ReactiveValidatingScreen
{
    public UserLoginViewModel()
    {
        var canLogin = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.UserName, x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && x.Length == 3);
        Login = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(canLogin, x => LoginImpl());
    }
}
```

It working fine, as expected.

ReactiveUI version - 6.5.0

Answer (score 4):

`ReactiveCommand` will subscribe lazily to the given `canExecute` observable, in your case a possible explanation would be that your `Validate` call is done too early and `OnNext` performed before the command is bound.

Try with a `ReplaySubject` (or `BehaviorSubject`) instead.

Comment: Thank you for answer. You push me to more investigation. And it was my fault( Problem was in my subscription code for `Changed` event, with default `Scheduler` which is used by `Throttle` I changed it to `Scheduler.CurrentThread` and it starts working.